# XML:Getting the position count an element with multiple occurences placed randomly

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an input xml file as follows:

```
<p><fig id="23"/><fig id="25"/></p>
<set>
<p><fig id="32"/></p>
<p><fig id="37"/></p>
<set>
<sec><fig id="52"/></sec>
```

and so on..

As we can see the element `fig` is placed anywhere in the file at random. I need to convert this to:

```
<p><fig>1</fig><fig>2</fig></p>
<set>
<p><fig>3</fig></p>
<p><fig>4</fig></p>
<set>
<sec><fig>5</fig></sec>
```

I need to give all the `figs` a serial number in sequence starting from 1 irrespective of its parent. Please guide as to how we can go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fig">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:number level="any"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```